Removing glass fiber from samples before mass spect run?
I would like some unbiased opinions and knowledge from you all if you have time. I am measuring Phosphorus content of snail and embryo samples. I am only interested in Phosphorous content.  I originally dissected these snails to 1) removed the shells, because we don't need the extra weight from a mostly calcium source and 2) separate embryos from their mothers. These embryos are quite tiny and difficult to weigh thus I used glass fiber filters to weigh the embryos on and to later dry them on. I did the same with the adults. For more information: My advisor suggested that I placed the embryos on glass fiber filter. My advisor does a different type of elemental analysis (ascorbate-molybdate colorimetry) then I do. We planned on me learning her techniques but because of COVID we were not comfortable with me coming out to their university. The glass fiber filters were fine for that procedure but they are now a problem in this one (acid digestion for ICP-MS). I decided to treat the snails and embryos the same so I placed all the snails and embryos were placed on glass fiber filters. The samples were then dried to remove water mass which caused them to stick to the glass fiber filters.
I prepared samples (as liquids) for ICP-Mass Spectrometry (ICP-MS) with an acid digestion. My simple procedure is add nitric acid and hydrogen peroxide to the sample and then run them in a microwave digestion system. I am putting this acid and my samples, which are attached to glass fiber filters, in a teflon vessel and then running them in the microwave. I can give you all more details if needed.
After my digestion sometimes there are still solids of samples, which is often not an issue because the solution can be shaked or heated to break apart any solids. However, unexpectedly there were some flakes that did not dissolve after shaking/heating. Stupidly, I decided to filter these samples with little guidance and I used a filter that had 70 um (micrometers!) pores, but the particle size allowance of the nebulizer (in the ICP-MS) is 40 um (micrometers!). The nebulizer was clogged by glass fibers. The tech used alot of their time trying to clean the nebulizer but decided to buy a new nebulizer. I was then given a warning that if something like this happens again I (technically my grant) will have to pay.
Originally, I thought the flakes were un-digested snails or embryos. The research specialist (RS) suggested that the flakes were actual glass fibers and that they should be dissolved with Hydrofluoric acid (HF). I do agree that the un-dissolved flakes are glass fibers. I was (still am) concerned about using HF - I am not a chemist and a rarely use dangerous chemicals. After our conversation I started the process to use HF (had not used HF yet). In the meantime I talked to a geochemistry professor about HF safety because I use his lab for the acid digestions. This professor suggested that I filter the samples instead of using HF to keep myself (and potentially students) safe. He offered me about 30 PVDF 0.45 um (micrometers!) pore filters with matching syringes. Instead of using HF I tried filtering about 10 samples, informed the RS, and ran those samples on ICP-MS. It seemed to have worked! The P content of the samples are comparable to P content of samples from an earlier run. And the nebulizer looks good!
After discussing this issue with my advisors and the RS over a couple of weeks I have decided to continue with filtering the samples instead of using HF to dissolve the glass fibers with the understanding that if there are any issues caused by the glass fiber flakes I will pay for the damage. However, the RS suggested HF again and I am paranoid. I would like to know what the implications of using HF are (right now filtering seems to have resolved the issues), but I need to do due diligence.
Q1: If I do use HF I need to use Boric Acid as well (unsure why). How could HF or Boric acid potentially change the chemistry of my samples? I don't believe there is any P in my glass fiber filters. I do not think HF nor Boric acid would affect my samples in a way that matters because I am only concerned with the P content of my samples. But I am not a chemist and I would love to hear what others know.
Q2: The particle size allowance for the nebulizer is 40 micrometers and I will be using a mesh that pores are 0.45 micrometers so that concern is taken care of! The mass spec is an Agilent (I can provide the model spec if required) - is there any other machine parts that have particle size allowances below 0.45 micrometers?
Q3: Lastly, I used PVDF filters. I have considered using PTFE. However, I really don't know the difference between these materials. What other filter materials could I use?

I am going to stick with PVDF filters because they are working. If anyone is interested in the difference between them: https://en.finetech-filter.com/what-is-the-difference-between-pvdf-and-ptfe.html#:~:text=The%20big%20difference%20between%20PTFE,aqueous%20and%20mild%20organic%20solutions.

Q4: Is there anything else I should think about before continuing the process?
Thank you all!

It is not clear if you were just interested in phosphorous content, would not you be using acid digestion followed by an elemental analysis technique like inductively coupled plasma-optical emission spectrometry (ICP-OES) or ICP-Mass Spectrometry (ICP-MS)? Is this the instrument you are talking about. Were you doing direct infusion? Anyway, no mass spectrometer is designed to handle insoluble particles in a fluid. Secondly, there was no need to use glass fiber. The anger of the research staff is well-justified.

One could have dessicated the tissues in an ordinary clean glass container. If you were measuring a specific phosphorous atom containing molecule, then it is a different story. Using HF is a very bad idea for a simple analysis. Geochemists need it because they have to dissolve silicate rocks. Boric acid serves to complex the fluoride ion. It should have never be used without formal training from the research institute. Typically the Environment Health and Safety Department in universities provides the requisite training and paper work.

We would be interested in  understanding what you are doing and why.  In the beginning of the second paragraph, you are mentioning your samples. What sort of samples are you using ? Samples of that ? Of snail ? Of embryos ? Of tissues ? Are these samples solid or not ? Why do you want to digest your samples ? You say that some flakes do dissolve. Well !  What do you mean about flakes ? Are your samples made of flakes ? Why are these flakes made of glass fibers ? There is no glass fibers in snails. Why do you introduce a nebulizer ? What for ? How do you measure phosphorous in flakes ?

@AChem, I have addressed your comments in the original post.

@Maurice These samples are snails (excluding shells) and embryos. We are not using laser ablation ICP-MS so these samples are acid digested to become liquid for ICP-MS. My samples are ashed beforehand so I would say that they are flakes in sense. However, the problem is not the samples digesting improperly but the glass fiber filters flaking off and leaving fibers in the acid digested solution. Glass fiber filters are involved because the snails and embryos were weighed and dried on them, the samples cannot be removed from the filter, so they are “digested” together.

@Maurice I cannot digest glass with nitric acid so the glass fiber filters are ran through the same process but they do leave behind flakes. I introduced the nebulizer because it was clogged with glass fibers. I measured P content by acid digesting my solid samples into liquid samples and then running those samples on ICP-MS.

@Bribina. If I understand you correctly, the main problem is not related to the snails, but to the glass fiber filters. So why do you continue using glass fiber filter ? Is it not possible to use paper filters or sintered glass beads filter ? Another point : You state that your samples are ashed beforehand. What does it mean ? Are your samples heated, pyrolized and reduced to ashes ?

@Maurice, I am not continuing to use glass fiber filters. The dietary portion of the experiment is complete and the snails/embryos have already been dissected and placed on the glass fiber filters. I cannot remove the samples from the filters. I do think it is possible to use other filters in the future, but I will likely not be doing this type of experiment again.
Ashing is when I put the samples in a muffle furnace at 500C for 2 hours. The samples are pyrolized and reduced to ash. However, some ash is stuck to the filter.
